# ember-testing visit promise not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to setup ember-testing with QUnit to test my Ember.js application following these blog post:
[Getting started with integration testing ember.js using ember-testing and qunit-rails](http://ianpetzer.wordpress.com/2013/06/14/getting-started-with-integration-testing-ember-js-using-ember-testing-and-qunit-rails/)

My problem is, that every time I try to visit a route with ember-testings visit helper, the `visit(<route>).then` promise doesn't get called, but the correct view is rendered.

Here my current Ember.js setup: (I also tried with beta)

- Ember      : 1.3.0-beta.1+canary.8f5b6e20
- Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.e7996c4d
- Handlebars : 1.1.1
- jQuery     : 1.10.2

**EDIT 1:**

QUnit only shows, that the test is running, no failure or success message.

**Test:**

```
module("Ember.js Library", {
  setup: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});

test("Check HTML is returned", function() {
  expect(2);
  visit("/").then(function() {
    ok(false, "Show me an error!");
  });
});
```

**Test setup (test_helper.js):**

```
document.write('<div id="ember-testing-container"><div id="ember-testing"></div></div>');
document.write('<style>#ember-testing-container { position: absolute; background: white; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 640px; height: 384px; overflow: auto; z-index: 9999; border: 1px solid #ccc; } #ember-testing { zoom: 50%; }</style>');

App.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();
```

**EDIT 2:**

QUnit seems to work correct. If I use the following Test, then QUnit test runner shows the correct failures. But if I include the assertion in the promise like above, then QUnit shows the test as running, but the test seems not to stop.

```
test("Check HTML is returned", function() {
  expect(2);
  ok(false, "Show me an error!");
});
```

Comment: Can you show your test code, and the code being tested?

Comment: I added my test and test-setup code. In the test I call index route `/`, but I also have tried other routes like `/login`. In case of login, the login view is rendered, but the test doesn't show success or failure message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in [Ember-Simple-Auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) plug-in, there was a [bug](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/35) in the version I used. I upgraded and now everything works as expected.

@kingpin: Thank you for your minimal working example, after comparing it to my code I realized, that something else must be the cause of the hang up and so I found the plug-in mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the qunit div, add this guy with your other document.writes

```
document.write('<div id="qunit"></div>');
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/inATaNE/1/edit

Comment: The qunit div is added by the qunit-rails gem automatically. I also see the test results. But as I described in my edits, the test doesn't seem to stop, if I use visit with a promise.